# Set JavaScript value to input

Tags: javascript, input

My goal to retrieve value from javascript and SHOW IN INPUT. I am able to view it on span BUT NOT input .

Below are my codes. Help will be appreciate! :)

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
function GetSelectedItem()
{
    var e = document.getElementById("staff");
    var strSel =  e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(strSel);
    $('#inputId').text(strSel);
}


</SCRIPT>

<input id="inputId">
```

Comment: Java is to JavaScript as Ham is to Hamster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For inputs, you have to change the value:

```
$('#inputId').val(strSel);
```

Comment: I have edited my question. I want to display in an input. Not span. Sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: @newbieinjavaversion2 All you really did to change the question was change the ID.  Because it's an input, you need to use the `.val` function to set the value.  The `#` in the jQuery selector means "find something with the following id."

Answer (score 3):

First you need to have an unique ID for each element. Then you can set the value like this:

```
$("#spanId").val(strSel);
```

**UPDATE:**

```
$("#inputId").val(strSel);
```

Comment: I have edited my question. I want to display in an input. Not span. Sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Answer (score 1):

why you are mixing JS and jQuery together?  Do one of these:

```
var e =  document.getElementById("staff");
```

could be directly

```
var strSel = ('#staff').val(); 
$('#spanId').val(strSel);
```

OR by purely JS you can write:

```
 document.getElementById("spanId").value = strSel;
```

Comment: I have edited my question. I want to display in an input. Not span. Sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: No problem...
$('#inputId').val(strSel) 
OR
document.getElementById("inputId").value = strSel;

just the ID change ..